# How to make batch file to select max value from many text files and append to new file

Tags: batch-file

We have a laser measurement system (LiDAR) which generates 10,000 text files for each measurement.  The format of each file is an array with 4 columns and looks like:

```
20     12     1.5     2.4
21     14     1.4     3.4
22     29     1.2     2.4
23     15     1.4     2.6
```

Is it possible to make a batch file that extracts the row with the largest value in column 2 and inserts it in a new text file?  i.e.:

```
22     29     1.2     2.4
```

And then does this for the remaining 9,999 text files and inserts the rows to the same file?  Or is this beyond the realm of DOS?  If so, any suggestions for an efficient way to do this?

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: To answer your "question": yes, it is possible. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here! Also read the article [mcve]!

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Assuming with `DOS` is meant windows batch,
some nested [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) commands will do:

- 1st will iterate through files `%%F` (assuming sorting by name is the desired order)
- 2nd reads the file line by line `%%L`
- 3rd splits the line at the default delimiter (space) into 4 fields `%%A-%%D`

If 2nd field is greater than previous Max it is replaced by it's value,
and the current line is stored as MaxLine.
The outer parentheses gather all echoed output in the file Lidar.Sum.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\10\10\SO_52748307.cmd
@Echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

( For /F "delims=" %%F in ('Dir /B/S/ON *.txt') do (
    Set Max=0
    For /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%%F") do (
      For /f "tokens=1-4" %%A in ("%%L") do (
        If %%B Gtr !Max! (
          set "Max=%%B"
          set "MaxLine=%%L"
        )
      )
    )
    Echo !MaxLine!
  )
) > Lidar.Sum
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(  rem Process all files
   for %%f in (*.txt) do (
      rem Get *the first line* from...
      rem Sort the file in reverse order by the 6th column = 2nd *data* column
      set "line="
      for /F "delims=" %%a in ('sort /R /+6 "%%f"') do (
         if not defined line (
            set "line=%%a"
            echo !line!
         )
      )
   )
) > output.dat
```